# Passing lambda expressions as parameters using reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, linq-expressions

I have a generic repository method call which is as follows

```
var result = Repository<MyDbClass>.Get(x => x.MyProperty1 == "Something"
&& (!x.MyProperty2.HasValue || x.MyProperty2 == "SomethingElse"));
```

I hope to call this method using reflection. I am mainly looking for a way to pass the lambda expression as a parameter using reflection.

**EDIT**

Actually my repository type will be known only at runtime. The tables under all these repositories are similar having some columns in common. It is on these columns the filter is applied. So I cannot pass an expression as it is.

```
public void SomeMethod<T, TR>(T repository, TR dataObject)
{
    var type = repository.GetType();
    var dataType = dataObject.GetType();
    var getMethod = type.GetMethod("Get");
    //How to invoke the method by passing the lambda as parameter(??)

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I invoke a method through reflection with a lambda expression as a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436716/how-do-i-invoke-a-method-through-reflection-with-a-lambda-expression-as-a-parame)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a `Func<TR, bool>`

```
var method = typeof(TR).GetMethod("Get");

if (method != null)
{
    method.Invoke(new Func<TR, bool>(
        (x) => x.MyProperty1 == "Something" /* etc... */));
}
```

By assuming you use LINQ methods in your `Get` method, you can just fill the func in like this

```
public IEnumerable<TR> Get<TR>(Func<TR, bool> func)
{
    return
        db.MyDbClassEntities.Where(func);
}
```

Comment: I will know my repository type only at runtime. Question edited for more clarity.

Comment: Can I really form an expression like that without the compiler knowing what TR is? What is the relation between MyProperty1 and TR?

Comment: You can't archive what you want if the compile hasn't any information about the TR type. Isn't there any interface implemented by the possible types?

Comment: can't I build an expression tree using TR as I do know the properties in TR used in the expression?

Comment: You could do this, but it would be very dangerous if an unexpected type is passed to the function. Do you know all types that may be passed to the function?

Comment: Yes, as I stated I will know the properties in TR as all possible types of TR will be of similar structure.

Comment: Isn't there a possibility to presribe the properties contained by all types that will be passed as TR in an interface and build a constraint for TR in the method? e.g. `public void SomeMethod<T, TR>(T repository, TR dataObject) where TR : IMyInterface`